# SQL. Get Ids by my order

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-order-by

My sql query gives me ids in this order:

```
3,5,7,1,9,2
```

What can I use to get my Ids:`1,3,2` in that order? (3,1,2). If I use

`WHERE ID IN(1,3,2)`

It gives me the following: `(1,2,3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What can I use to get my Ids:1,3,2 in that order? (3,1,2).

You can have a **CASE expression** in the **ORDER BY clause** to customize the sorting of the output.

For example,

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT 3 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 5 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 7 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 1 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 9 ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 2 ID FROM dual
  8  )
  9   SELECT id
 10  FROM   data
 11  WHERE  id IN( 1, 3, 2 )
 12  ORDER  BY CASE ID
 13              WHEN 3 THEN 1
 14              WHEN 1 THEN 2
 15              WHEN 2 THEN 3
 16            END
 17  /

        ID
----------
         3
         1
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: A good reason why only DBAs should be allowed to write queries :-) I know it delivers what OP wanted but I suspect the better answer would have been "don't do this" or "sort it how you want _after_ the event". This is both a maintenance headache and a performance killer if you ever need to scale. Still, for reasons already stated, no downvote from me.

Comment: Well, I agree with you to some extent. But, it is not always necessary that someone asked such a question to implement the suggestion on production server. Basically, such questions are homework assignments or just learning purpose. It could be understood with the quality of the question. Regarding *don't do this* suggestion, well I could have said that, but imagine the amount of explanation I would have to provide for such trivial question.